# How to fix "Cannot Find Module node_sqlite3.node" while it works in production but throws this error on publish

Tags: node.js, sqlite, electron, electron-packager

I am Stuck in a problem, actually the problem is "my project works fine in production build while i do 'electron .' but when i publish the app with electron-packager and try to run it, it say 'Cannot Find Module node_sqlite3.node',

I tried installing sqlite3 using npm install --save sqlite3 --build-from source but no luck

Here is my Dev Env
node -v 10.15.3
npm -v 6.4.1
electron 4.1.3
sqlite3 4.0.6

I say again it works on electron . but doesn't work when I publish the app with electron-packager

i execute the following command for publishing

```
"publish": "electron-packager . Order-MGT --platform=win32 --arch=ia32  --prune=true --out=dist --ignore=.gitignore --ignore=README.md"
```

## package.json

{
  "name": "sample17",
  "version": "2.1.0",
  "description": " Inventory Management System",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron .",
    "rebuild": "electron-rebuild -f -w sqlite3",
    "publish": "electron-packager . Order-MGT --platform=win32 --arch=ia32  -- 
     prune=true --out=dist --ignore=.gitignore --ignore=README.md --version- 
     string.CompanyName=SaqiXPRO --version-string.FileDescription=SaqiXPRO"
   },
  "dependencies": {
    "ejs-electron": "^2.0.3",
    "node-gyp": "^3.8.0",
    "nodemailer": "^5.1.1",
    "sqlite3": "^4.0.6"
  },
  "author": "SaqiXPRO",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^4.1.3",
    "electron-packager": "^13.1.1",
    "electron-rebuild": "^1.8.4"
  }
}

I want to make it working as it does on electron . but i can't quite understand what to do please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had solved the problem by the doing the following

I installed C++ Build Tools 2015 or later and the issue was resolved